# Doesn't tabulary honor the table width without wrapped lines?

Tags: width, tabulary

With this MWE, I try to recreate a `tabularx` table with `tabulary` (the `C` column type being builtin):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
    tabularx \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|C|}
    \hline
    tabulary \\
    \hline
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

But the `tabulary` table does not have `linewidth`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: by default ty only sets a maximum (I was going to say this was a documented feature, but apparently not:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle fine for me, thanks!